# Sharing JARS with Maven Nexus Server... Only seeing update on workstation with common code

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I am trying to setup a Maven Nexus Server for my firm to share common JARs that we build inhouse. I use my workstation (call it workstation 1) to build the common JAR and I then do a `mvn deploy` to deploy it to the Nexus Maven Server. Then I add it in the dependencies in the pom.xml of the project that needs it and I do my `mvn package` and everything is great.

Now if I change the common code and I run `mvn deploy` with the same version number and then rerun the `mvn package` on the second project, it will see the changes and everything is great.

Now lets move to workstation2.  If I do a `mvn package` on the project that needs the common code everything is fine. But if the common code changes and I rerun the `mvn package` command it looks like it's going to my local repository on the workstation and using that version, not the new version in Nexus!

So my questions are the following...

1. Does `mvn deploy` save a copy in the local repository before the nexus repository?
2. How do I make the project check the nexus repository for the most up-to-date file before the local repository on the workstation?

The code is a accept SNAPSHOT so I would like it to be updated each time the user try to access it.

Comment: Can you share your `pom.xml` file (or at least the parts relating to the deployment)?

Comment: Also, please share the `settings.xml` file where you reference your Nexus server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.. I had to add  always to the snapshot settings in my settings.xml

Comment: I thought it would be that (hence my comments above) :-)

Answer (score 1):

1) maven consult the local repository and only for a miss it aks the online repository (nexus)

2) I do not know

Anyway: (Except for SNAPSHOTS) you should not modifiy a released artefact without updating its version too!

Answer (score 1):

You can run `mvn -U package`. With -U Maven will always check the repositories (in your case Nexus) for newer SNAPSHOT versions of your dependencies.

You can also add a configuration to your settings.xml to look always for new versions of dependencies. See the [Settings reference](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories), the configuration is named `<updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>`